# Main domain and subdomain are same contain

Tags: seo, domains, wordpress, subdomain, ranking

One website `example.com` and second website is subdomain of `example.com` like `example.example.com`.  Both website are same in terms of both content and functionality but written in different programming languages. Main website `example.com` is in PHP and subdomain website `example.example.com` is in WordPress.

1. Which one will get good results? Does coding platform matter?
2. The subdomain is a keyword like `keyword.example.com`. It is getting ranked well, why?
3. Is it harmful to me like duplicate content like this?

Answer (score 1):

1. The CMS you can use doesn't really matter for SEO unless the CMS has been thinking regarding SEO (it's the case for WordPress)
2. There are too many possible reasons, so hard to answer you on this. However, be careful on duplicate content issues if two websites have the same content (main website and a subdomain are two different websites for search engines).
3. See point 2.